# I need to know if.my example for this problem solved

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

Let $f(x)=\sup(x^3, x^2+1)$, $I=[1,4]$

$\sup(x^3)=64,\ \inf(x^3)=1$

$\sup(x^2+1)=17,\  \inf(x^2+1)=2$

So $\sup(x^3,x^2+1)=\sup(64,17) =64$

Is this correct, can I have good example.

Answer (score 1):

No, you misunderstood the definition of the function $f$: it is the function which, for each $x\in[14]$, takes the value $\sup(x^3,x^2+1)$. For instance

- $f(1)=\sup(1^3,1^2+1)=2$,
- $f(2)=\sup(2^3,2^2+1)=8$,

&c.

Comment: I think you meant to put sup, instead of sum.

Comment: @cmk: Yes. For my excuse, it's getting late here. Thank you for pointing the typos!